# Adobe Acrobat watermark in Arabic Language

Tags: javascript, pdf, adobe, arabic-support

I tried to write arabic (rtl) watermark:

```
this.addWatermarkFromText({
    cText: "شکرا",
    nTextAlign:app.constants.align.center,
    cFont: "Arial",
    nFontSize:72,
    aColor: color.black,
    nOpacity: 0.5
});
```

but it appears on page as : `ارک ش`
is there a way to fix it?

(I use Adobe Acrobat Pro DC 2015.)